# How to test Future Method from anonymous window

Tags: future

i'm tring to insert phone field from future method, so i'm passing account id from anonymous window. But i'm getting error.
code :-

```java
public class futureTest {
    @future
    public static void main(set<id> Accountid){
        List<Account> NewList = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> AccList = [select id from account where Id in : Accountid];
        for(Account a :AccList){
            a.Phone = 'FutureTest';
            NewList.add(a);
        }
         insert NewList;
    }
}
```

anonymous window:-

```java
futureTest f = new futureTest();
f.main(001Iw000002LI91IAG);
```

error:-
[image: error img]

Comment: You have at least one syntax error in your code. Have you tried to debug it? Where do you think it might be? The message tells you exactly where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question directly, by calling the `main()` method.

The way you've attempted to do that contains some rudimentary mistakes.

- futureTest's `main()` method is a *static* method, not an instance method. Static methods are called using the class name directly and without the `new` operator.

  - e.g. `MyClass.myStaticMethod();`
- Ids require single quotes around them, just like strings

  - e.g. `Id myId = '001000000000001AAA';`
- The method you're trying to call does not take a single Id as an argument, but a set of Ids. You need to pass the correct data type into your method (this is the client's, the code which calls the method, responsibility)

  - e.g. `MyClass.staticMethodThatTakesASet(new Set<String>{'abc'});`

Comment: There is also a very obvious issue in your `@future` method itself, but that's out of scope for this question. If I see a follow-up question asking about that with as little effort as this question displayed, I will downvote and vote to close it.